# vb.net Closing multiple form and open another form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have 2 forms open, my current form is in dialog box. Now I want to close that 2 forms and open another form.

```
 Dim frmStg2 As New frmStageTwo
 Dim frmStg1 As New frmStageOne

        frmStg2.Show()
        Me.Close()
        frmStg1.Close()
```

But this code seems not working the frmStageOne is still open and showing frmStageTwo but I can't view that form.

[This is what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hDO2.png)

Comment: which one is `Me`, the dialog?  Is one of them the main, start up form?

Comment: Yes it is the dialog, none of them is a start up form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to close a form instance that has not yet been opened.

When you use the `New` keyword you are declaring a new instance of an object (a `Form` in this case) which has it's own version of the base class's properties and fields.

In order to close an already existing instance of the form you can loop through the `Application.OpenForms` property.

```
For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
    If frm.GetType() Is GetType(frmStageOne) Then
        frm.Close()
    End If
Next
```

---

You could actually make it a method:

```
Public Sub CloseFormsOfType(ByVal TargetForm As Form)
    For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If frm.GetType() Is TargetForm.GetType() Then
            frm.Close()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

...and just call:

```
CloseFormsOfType(frmStageOne)
```

Comment: Thanks sir, it saves me! :)

Comment: @PauloRomulo please mark my post as the accepted answer by pressing the green tick next to the post. This will show your gratitude to the contributor but it will also indicate to other users that have the same problem that this is working for you. :)